# How to read a csv file(that is mainly in double) into a 2d Array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, data-structures, file-io

I have a Csv file ( That Csv file is basically in floats and integers seperated by commas with Rows = 4000 and columns = 3).I wannt to read that data into a 2d array.What is the simplest code to do this.
Note : we cannot use vectors or any advanced stuff for this.

I did tried to use the stringstreams but couldn't find answers to how the file pointer goes to the next line after reading one line.Can someone please share me the code...?

Comment: Hmmm, search first, "C++ read CSV file double 2d array".  Always search first.

Comment: vectors are not advanced. Not using vectors but 2d c-arrays is so much more difficult than using vectors. When you have special requirements you need to name them. "advanced stuff" is too vague